# How do I recreate Ctrl+D in VS Code (selectively find & edit multiple occurences at once)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've deleted the above key binding by mistake as it had stopped working for some unknown reason. I've tried searching for how I add this back but have hit a brick wall. When I open the keybindings.json file from the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) with the Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON) command all I see is this and nothing else:

```
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+d",
        "command": "-editor.action.addSelectionToNextFindMatch",
        "when": "editorFocus"
    }
]
```

Comment: The `-` in `"command": "-..."` means that this item is disabled. Simply removing this `{...}` section should work.

Comment: Removed the '-' in the command section to no effect. Is this not a default key binding and  therefore shouldn't I be able to simply reset the key bindings to get it back? Sounds so simple you would think.

Comment: If above IS your keybindings.json file just delete it and you have your default bindings, or as HolyBC says just remove this `ctrl+d` binding

Comment: Have done and still not working. I'm looking at the built in keybindings it's an extensive list I now see I have 2 x 'Add Selection To Next Find Match' bindings with a keybinding 'Ctrl+D'!!  Previously when I deleted one the other disappeared as well. Not sure how I've ended up with 2 or why neither are working :(